# TypeScript + Node.js FileSystem issue

Tags: node.js, filesystems, typescript

I have a simple typescipt program

```
/// <reference path="node-definitions/node.d.ts" />
import fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync("test.txt","HelloWorld");
```

when I run it, it says that fs is empty
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygvfi8us4mdignd/Screenshot%202015-06-11%2010.11.12.png?dl=0

the generated js code is correct https://www.dropbox.com/s/egl06maalnsd04e/Screenshot%202015-06-11%2010.21.24.png?dl=0

if I require other modules, for instance require(“path”) all is ok
but require(“fs”) always returns empty Object
as I see they are declared inside node.d.ts in the same way (“path” and “fs” modules)
also I have tried different versions of node.d.ts and node.js (0.10 - 0.12)
Maybe someone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that generated code override native 'require' function. Try to use --module parameter when compiling typescript, e.g. 'tsc --module commonjs App.ts'.

Answer (score 0):

For nodejs compile your typescript with `commonjs` module format i.e.

```
tsc App.ts --module commonjs
```